# Expect script stops exactly at 56th iteration

Tags: unix, tcl, expect

I wrote an expect script to detect a condition when my box suddenly stops responding to ssh/telnet requests. I have seen other answers that talk about closing a spawned session and performing a **wait** operation. But I am failing to get my wait to work. Please help.

**Problem 1**. While testing I see that my script stops exactly at 56th iteration. Unable to locate this.

The error it shows is below:

```
spawn telnet 10.16.206.15
too many programs spawned?  could not create pipe: too many open files
    while executing
"spawn telnet $ip_addr"
    ("while" body line 8)
    invoked from within
"while (1) {
                        match_max 100000
                        set hostname "Dell"
                        set user "admin"
                        set passwd "admin"
                        set timeout 20
                        set ip_addr "10.16.206.15"
                        sp..."
    (file "./trigger_on_cond.sh" line 3)
```

**Problem 2**. Also, I see that "wait" (commented) actually blocks the script. As I knew, it has the same function as that of UNIX wait() call.

**Failing script is below**

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
    set count 0
    while (1) {
            match_max 100000
            set hostname "MyBox"
            set user "admin"
            set passwd "admin"
            set timeout 50
            set ip_addr "xx.yy.zz.15"
            spawn telnet $ip_addr

            expect {
                    "Login:" {
                        send "$user\r"
                        expect "Password"
                        send "$passwd\r"
                    }
                    "Unable to connect to remote host" {

                        exec date > /f10/topout.txt
                        sleep 2
                        exec top -b -o res all > /mypath/topout.txt
                        exec f10livecore sysd
                        sleep 20
                        exec top -b -o res all >> /mypath/topout.txt
                        sleep 10
                        exec fstat >>  /mypath/topout.txt
                        sleep 20
                        exec ps -laux >>  /mypath/topout.txt
                        exit
                    }
                    timeout {
                        send \003
                        exec date > /mypath/topout.txt
                        sleep 2
                        exec top -b -o res all > /mypath/topout.txt
                        exec f10livecore sysd
                        sleep 20
                        exec top -b -o res all >> /mypath/topout.txt
                        sleep 10
                        exec fstat >>  /mypath/topout.txt
                        sleep 20
                        exec ps -laux >>  /mypath/topout.txt
                        sleep 30
                        exit
                    }
            }

            expect {
                "$hostname>" {
                        #send "quit\r"
                        #expect eof
                        send "show ver\r"
                        set count [expr $count + 1]
                        puts $count
                        send "quit\r"
                        expect eof

                }
                "$hostname#" {
                        send "show ver\r"
                        expect "$hostname#"
                        #send "quit\r"
                        #expect eof
                        send "show ver\r"
                        set count [expr $count + 1]
                        puts $count
                        send "quit\r"
                        expect eof

                }
                timeout {
                        send \003
                        exec date > /mypath/topout.txt
                        sleep 2
                        exec top -b -o res all > /mypath/topout.txt
                        exec killcore sysd
                        sleep 20
                        exec top -b -o res all >> /mypath/topout.txt
                        exit
                    }

            }

            #wait
            sleep 30
        }
```

Comment: Why do you use expect with telnet, and not a (normal) tcl socket?

Answer (score 0):

The spawned telnet processes are never closed and therefore you reach the limit of 'max open files'. (linux: `ulimit -n`)

Simply try to replace `expect eof` with `wait` in order to wait for the telnet process to be finished.

A non-graceful way would be:

```
    ...
    set pid [exp_pid -i $spawn_id]
    exec kill -9 $pid
    wait
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks. As said in my problem statement it is stuck at wait and never comes out of it. I need to press Ctrl+D to come out of hung script.

Comment: Also if you could help on, if it is permissible to wait after expect eof